# How to stop movement and/or rotation of a Unity gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a small game that is based on the Roll-A-Ball tutorial from Unity, though I haven't used the actual tutorial. I incorporated a respawn mechanic, but if you are moving around when you die, then after you respawn, you still have that momentum after you land. I have tried to fix this, but I am not sure how since I am still pretty new at using Unity. I have a video that shows this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1752bPBDVOe2emN_hmnlPaD4uaJQITpsP

Here is the C# script that handles respawn:

```
public class PlayerBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody PlayerRB;
    public bool Dead;
    private int timer;
    public GameObject Particles;
    public bool InRespawn;

    void Update()
    {
        PlayerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         if (Dead)
        {
            StartCoroutine("Respawn");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Respawn()
    {
        InRespawn = true; //Used to prevent movement during respawn.
        PlayerRB.useGravity = false;
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, 4, 0);
        transform.rotation = new Quaternion(-80, 0, 0, 0); // Resets position.
        Dead = false;
        Instantiate(Particles, transform); // Adds respawn particle effect.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        Destroy(this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
        PlayerRB.useGravity = true;
        PlayerRB.AddForce(0, 400, 0); // Does a little hop.
        InRespawn = false; // Tells the game that respawn is finished.
    }
}
```

Comment: that means if `dead` variable will be true when you will die

Comment: Set the velocity of the rigid body to an empty vector.

Comment: instead of using `Update` for polling the state you should rather implement this more event driven and start the coroutine wherever you set `Dead` to true

Comment: @derHugo I thought about doing that, but I am planning on making traps and other such things that could cause the player to respawn. I assumed that having them change the variable would be better than starting the coroutine, but honestly I wouldn't know which is better.

Comment: well ... you start a Coroutine anyway though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero out the rigidbody's velocity when the respawn occurs:

```
IEnumerator Respawn()
{
    PlayerRB.velocity = Vector3.zero;

    // ... rest of method
}
```

As a sidenote, you probably don't need to run `GetComponent` on every frame. It's an expensive operation so it's best to do it as infrequently as you can get away with:

```
void Start()
{
    PlayerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}


void Update()
{
     if (Dead)
    {
        StartCoroutine("Respawn");
    }
}
```

---

If instead you would like to disable all physics interactions with the player while it is dead, you can set it to be kinematic during that time. Just be sure to unset `isKinematic` before adding force to it.

```
IEnumerator Respawn()
{
    PlayerRB.isKinematic = true;

    // ... rest of method

    PlayerRB.isKinematic = false;

    PlayerRB.useGravity = true;
    PlayerRB.AddForce(0, 400, 0); // Does a little hop.
    InRespawn = false; // Tells the game that respawn is finished.
}
```

Comment: I moved `GetComponent` to `Start()`, which really seems like a good idea. However, when I put in the `PlayerRB.velocity = Vector3.zero;` all it did was slow down the player's momentum somewhat. I tried running that line when I hit a certain key so that I could see what happens if I do it while moving, but the player just slowed down; they didn't stop completely, which is what I'm aiming for. I also tried running the line several times with a .1 second delay between them using a `for` loop, hoping that would cancel the momentum, but the player still only slowed down. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AMiller42 hard to say without seeing your movement code .. apparently you keep setting a velocity or AddForce somewhere else. To be sure you could additionally activate `PlayerRB.isKinematic = true` and deactivate it later when movement shall be allowed again.

Comment: @derHugo Using `isKinematic` works perfectly! It is giving me exactly the results I was looking for. You should post that as an answer to my question so that I can mark it as answered.

Comment: @derhugo, mind if I edit this answer to include that solution?

Comment: @AMiller42 Just as a heads up if you do go with setting `isKinematic`, if you have things like walls or elevators or platforms  that could/should push you while you're dead, you won't be able to rely on the physics engine to have them do that, you'll need your character's movement code or something else detect them and move accordingly. It might be better to include your character movement code in the question so we can fix it another way than with using `isKinematic` during death, or players might be able to get out of bounds by dying (unless that's an intentional design choice of course)

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks for letting me know. I don't think I have to worry about that. I actually originally had the out of bounds problem at first, which is why I made the `InRespawn` variable, so that other scripts, specifically the controller script, would not be able to work while the character was respawning. I assume that this fix will still work with the `isKinematic` fix, but I'll definitely have to keep in mind the physics differences.

Comment: @Ruzihm no, sure go ahead ;) I still think it's rather kind of a hot fix but the real solution would probably be disabling user input or what ever causes the movement in the first place in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

make a bool in your code like this

```
bool isDead=false;
```

then make it true when you die
the add this into you update

```
if(isDead){
rb.velocity=vector3.zero;
}
```

this will stop you objects movements if it is dead